# keep every selected file for upload into list of files (AngularJS/php slim framework)

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, drag-and-drop, slim

I am creating an intranet module to add reports for an entreprise. I want to add mulitiple files into it and keep them shown in a list below for upload.
I want that every time they select a file for upload, the others are not deleted. I couldn't find this, I only made the upload of one single file or multiple files: in once click and not every time I click to add new one.
Hope I can find any idea.
Sorry for my english, Thanks!

Here is the view code where I can only upload one single file.

```html
<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="val_avatarUser">Rapport </label>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="file" id="val_avatarUser"  file-model="myFile"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" ng-click="addNote()" ng-hide="hide_add"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i> Ajouter</button>
```

Comment: Can you show your code and tell us where you're stuck? I want a unicorn, but without telling anyone where they live, i doubt anyone can help with that.

Comment: You are right. I added some code.